# How to get price of Barcode from zBar sdk?

Tags: ios, iphone, barcode, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk

I have implemented ZBar sdk on my project.
The code work perfectly. But every time it scan the code it will give me a number not the barcode price.
And My client ask me to show price on label not code.

So how can I show code on label that is my question?

Please check my code:

```
. h file
@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIImageView *resultImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  UITextView *resultText;


.m file

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

resultImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 250)];
resultImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:resultImage];



resultText=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 380, 300, 100)];
resultText.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
resultText.text=@"";
resultText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
resultText.delegate =self;
resultText.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
resultText.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
resultText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
[self.view addSubview:resultText];
//[txtGap release];




UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(scanButtonTapped)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
[button setTitle:@"Get Bar Code" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 500, 120, 35);
[self.view addSubview:button];
}



- (void) scanButtonTapped
{
NSLog(@"TBD: scan barcode here...");

// ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
// TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

// EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];

// present and release the controller

[self presentViewController:reader animated:NO completion:nil];



 //  [self presentModalViewController: reader animated: YES];
 [reader release];


 }


- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
 // ADD: get the decode results
 id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
 [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
 ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
 for(symbol in results)
    // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
    break;

// EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
resultText.text = symbol.data;

// EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
resultImage.image =
[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

// ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)

[reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


// [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Comment: you must include price in bar code. which you can receive it after scanning.

Answer (score 4):

ZBar will only give you the EAN/UPC code of the bar code (13 numbers), NOT the price. You have to ask a web service (for example) with the given code to retrieve the price.

As far as I know, there is no way that scanning the bar code gives you the price without associating the code to a price (in your app, or by performing a HTTP request)

Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Bar code is mostly give the information of product not the price so its up to you how you can return the price of the product, best way which i can guess you must have a table at server side to compare with your bar code and return price of the product which could be show on label